# Is there a way to package an ASP.NET Core app, using NuGet or otherwise?

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, octopus-deploy

I'm building a ASP.NET Core app which I can publish using `dotnet publish`. So far, so good.

I'm interested in packaging that app so I can publish it on a NuGet server. `dotnet pack`, however, doesn't seem to contain enough information to recreate the website on its own -- just the dll file.

Is there a way to create a NuGet package, through `dotnet pack` or some other method, or do I need to manually package the files in the output directory myself?

Comment: To me, NuGet is a tool to manage dependencies, meaning libraries. You create a package, and then reference it somewhere else. What does it mean to "reference" a web site?

Comment: @AlexBuyny NuGet packages can be used as a delivery mechanism for websites. Octopus uses them, for example, to handle delivery and versioning: http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Packaging+Web+Apps

Answer (score 5):

You can manually configure `packOptions` setting in `project.json` file to contain folders/files that you need, for example

```
"packOptions": {
    "files": {
        "include": [ "wwwroot/**.*", "Views/**.*" ] --add anything else that you need in here
    }
}
```

Then run

```
dotnet pack
```

This worked for me. The package now contains images, js files etc.

Comment: Thanks! I wish it didn't require manual enumeration, but since it's already somewhat required for `dotnet publish`, that may be a satisfactory solution for now.

Answer (score 4):

As of 1/2017, there's no way one step way to do this, though ASP.NET Core is so fresh at the moment that I'm still hoping for a newer and better answer.

The best way to create a single file package for a ASP.NET Core website is to publish your app using `dotnet publish`, and package the directory using a ZIP utility (or [Octo.exe](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Packaging+Web+Apps) if you need a NuGet package for Octopus).

Current tools as of 2017/1: Octopack, which uses NuGet, [cannot package](http://help.octopusdeploy.com/discussions/questions/9315-tc-dotnet-core-octopack#comment_40864211) .NET Core projects. NuGet itself is a minimal tool which requires a manifest or project file to work, and `dotnet pack` will only pack up the source files, and not assets (see [the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41493553/40352) for ways around that).